# Language settings for .runnssettings in Palywright

Tags: c#, playwright

how can I set language settings in .runnsettings with C#? I tried to do it with BrowserContext. It doesn't work.

```
<RunSettings>
<!-- MSTest adapter -->
<MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
        <Workers>4</Workers>
        <Scope>ClassLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
</MSTest>
<!-- General run configuration -->
<RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
        <!-- For debugging selectors, it's recommend to set the following environment variable -->
        <DEBUG>pw:api</DEBUG>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
</RunConfiguration>
<!-- Playwright -->
<Playwright>
    <BrowserName>chromium</BrowserName>
    <ExpectTimeout>5000</ExpectTimeout>
    <LaunchOptions>
        <Headless>true</Headless>
        <Channel>msedge</Channel>
        <SlowMo>1000</SlowMo>
    </LaunchOptions>
</Playwright>
<BrowserContext>    
    <Locale>de-DE</Locale>      
</BrowserContext>
```